# Problemas al guardar un dato

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de insertar un dato que extraigo de una lista, pero al momento de elegir el dato (ej: Esteban), solo guarda la `E`.

Aquí un fragmento del código.

```
<td>
    <select name="noap" id="noap">
        <option value="<?php  $row['noap'] ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['noap'] ?></option>

        <?php
            $sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM conductor ORDER BY nomapell';
            $result3 = mysqli_query($connex, $sql3);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
        ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row3['nomapell']; ?>" > <?php echo $row3['nomapell']; ?></option>
        <?php  
                }
            }
        ?> 

    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Hola..
Lo mas probable es que el error este cuando envías los datos a la base de datos, publica el código completo.

Comment: podrias poner la parte donde insertas en la bd !!

Comment: verificaste que el Value del Option tenga valor? Porque al ver tu código noto que falta el "echo".
Debería ser <option value="<?php echo $row['noap']?>" selected="selected">
en vez de <option value="<?php $row['noap']?>" selected="selected">

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar colocando esto: [] al name y al id, el script que recibe el código tienes esto:

```html
$chkcount = count($id);
for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++)
 {

 if ($connex->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connex->connect_error);
} 


y el uptade table etc
```